# sending data from serial port to node app

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, arduino, real-time

I'm trying to connect arduino and nodejs app.I have an python script that is reading data from serial port.

```
import socket
import serial

if __name__ == "__main__":

    while True:
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
        serial_read = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
        signal = serial_read.readline()
        if "B" in signal:
            s = signal.split("B")
            client.sendall(s[1])
```

and sending to localhost.My server side:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler).listen(8080),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs = require('fs');


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

});

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                    res.writeHead(500);
                    return res.end('Error loading index.html');
                    }

        res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(data);
        setInterval(function(){
        io.sockets.emit('pulse', {'pulse': data});
    }, 1000);


  });
}
```

client:

```
<script>
      var socket = io.connect();

      socket.on('pulse', function(data){
        $('#pulse').text(data.pulse);
      });
    </script>
    <div id="pulse"></div> <br>
```

My problem is that I can't show datas correctly on the page.Is there any problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

HTML supports only ascii content if the serialport has binary or unicode data then you need to  use apprppriate encoding to display it on the page

Comment: I guess my code is incorrect.How can I listen to the socket with http server?

Comment: I am not a expert in node.js